# tfs code review using shelveSet

Tags: tfsbuild

I was wondering if I can use tfs shelve set for code review and then gated check-in.
The idea behind is to fix any issue in the code (if any) and then close review by submiting gate-in checking using build definition.

When I was testing this solution everything was fine, until the place when I was trying to retrieve code review details (see below)

Shelve set is deleted after successful build (that is OK for me), and all  code review entries too (as that was pointing to shelve set).

---

### Is there a way to preserve code review entries?

### or merge it with successful change set?

---

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use tfs shelve set for code review and then gated check-in.

It can be achieved. Code review the shelvest then queue build and select the shelveset also mark "Check in changes after successful build"
[image]

---

Since you have mentioned, the shelveset is checked in. And the code review is associate with the shelveset.

So this question is the same as **[how to check in shelveset and prevent deleting shelvesets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875439/how-to-prevent-tfs-from-deleting-shelvesets-that-were-checked-in-via-a-queued-bu)**. Shelveset are kind of pending changes. Check in pending changes and keep the pending changes. Definitely impossible. So there is **no way** to preserve the code review (for shelveset), if you had checked in the shelveset.

Comment: the question is: Is there a way to preserve code review entries? or merge it with successful change set